# Jquery image cropper

Tags: php, jquery

I'm using a plug in to perform cropping of an image.

If you download this plug in  http://www.webmotionuk.co.uk/php-jquery-image-upload-and-crop-v11/ ,you can see this below line ,what does this do $max_file*1048576

If you see $max_file ,it is hardcoded with 3,they've also mentioned as MB. What does that * 1048576 do.

```
if ($userfile_size > ($max_file*1048576)) {
            $error.= "Images must be under ".$max_file."MB in size";
        }
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

`1048576 (bytes) = 1MB` So  `3 * 1048576 (bytes)  = 3MB`

Comment: :Thank you for answering.if i upload an image which is more than 3 MB,it is not showing image exceed error insteadit is showing select an image.What does this $large_image_prefix = "resize_";

Comment: Just like the comment in the code is telling you: The prefix(bit.ly/Ml2AL7) name to large image. If you're getting the "Select an image for upload" message, then perhaps the name of your file input field is not "upload" as it should be.

Comment: :It is upload.Can you direct me a good cropper plug in.I've few fields too.When some one selects image then fill all the fields then when user press submits,it has to upload the image then user should be able to crop it.I'm not finding even one with my requirement.

Comment: :Button should have a name as upload and input type="file" should have name ="image" Which is what i've been using.Can u test it on your local host.